# Control Identification Issue

Tags: winforms, coded-ui-tests

I have a bit of a strange situation. Our application under test contains the version number in the title bar of the main window. Eg: Photoshop 6.1.06

During development cycles the version changes frequently.

At runtime I can inject code into the UI map to update the search properties dynamically pulled from the ApplicationUnderTest.Exe path using something like this:

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Constants.ApplicationUndertestPath);
string version = versionInfo.FileVersion; 
_map.MainWin.SearchProperties[DXTestControl.PropertyNames.Name] =
 string.Format("Photoshop : {0}", version);
```

So far so good, but the problem comes with control identification using the UIMap and Coded UI Recorder.

Here I tried to change the search property of the main window from instead of Equal operator to a Contains.

Something like this:

```
this.SearchProperties.Add(new
PropertyExpression(DXTestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Photoshop :", 
PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
```

However the newly identified controls are not added to the same MainWin tree structure, Instead it creates a lookup based on the exact version and adds another MainWin.version number instance to the UIMap.

If I set the exact version in my MainWin using an Equal operator - then everything works fine and new controls are appended to the MainWindow ui map branch structure, but this means maintaining the UIMap with each build.

How can I get around this?